# is question review appropriate for meta?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions, meta

Is it on-topic here to ask how you can improve a particular question before posting it on main?

Or is it required that the question be posted on main first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is on-topic sure.  Asking questions about how to ask a better question or provide a better answer is encouraged.  You do not need to post the question to the main site first.